# New Sails.js app gets infinite redirect in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I had created an empty application with Sails.js ver. 1.0.2. I used a 'Web App' option of 'sails new' command. It works fine, when started at localhost, both in development and production environments.

Next, I want to put this application into Heroku.

What I've done:

- created new app in Heroku with "heroku create";
- initialized new git repo in my application root;
- created Procfile in my app root with text: "web: npm start"
- changed production environment config (in \config\env\production.js):

  - Changed sockets.onlyAllowOrigins and custom.baseUrl values to "http://myappname.herokuapp.com"
  - Changed http.trustProxy value to "true"
- set heroku remote for my repo with "heroku git:remote -a myappname"
- added, committed and pushed my repo to Heroku with "git push heroku master"

It builds successfully with some warnings, but the worst thing is that app is not working. Each requests causes redirect loop with heroku[router] to the same address.

Here is a part of Heroku log:

```
2018-05-16T12:52:25.991036+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: -------------------------------------------------------
2018-05-16T12:52:25.991290+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: :: Wed May 16 2018 12:52:25 GMT+0000 (UTC)
2018-05-16T12:52:25.991366+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: Environment : production
2018-05-16T12:52:25.991441+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: Port        : 37749
2018-05-16T12:52:25.991589+00:00 app[web.1]: debug: -------------------------------------------------------
2018-05-16T12:52:26.645022+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-05-16T12:52:27.762757+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=ee575a91-305f-4518-af9f-537ceccbc3cf fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=48ms status=302 bytes=523 protocol=https
2018-05-16T12:52:28.039174+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=980d6e72-b03c-4704-af97-56c7f9debc8b fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=http
2018-05-16T12:52:28.185571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=b46a235f-fbf7-4404-a4b7-0a95bb1a0254 fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=http
2018-05-16T12:52:28.339593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=03bbd460-3200-4158-a555-33c20262a212 fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=http
2018-05-16T12:52:28.484756+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=af7303b1-f04c-431b-93b5-9e8b148a6721 fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=http
2018-05-16T12:52:28.637541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=1535454e-58b0-41d2-821d-317d7ebabeeb fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=8ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=http
2018-05-16T12:52:28.788965+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=559d3426-78b9-4b65-8063-c44eb728d825 fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=http
2018-05-16T12:52:28.936187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=e4ad129d-746b-490c-9d0d-c77966b98d46 fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=http
2018-05-16T12:52:29.082496+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=92a66cab-344e-410d-9ebf-8c8bddec80bd fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=http
2018-05-16T12:52:29.233773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=92f3734c-6e37-48d6-9849-807b53f1e1f7 fwd="83.45.25.57" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=http
```

Tried to set custom.baseUrl as HTTP and HTTPS with no difference.
Where did things go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

@marvin, you don't need to create a Procfile in heroku.
just when you deploy your app it will run automatically and set environment production.

Comment: Did this help? I have the same issue. @marvin